# Find the formula for a $\sum ^m _{k=0} \sqrt[3]{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the $\sqrt[3]{0}+\sqrt[3]{1}+\sqrt[3]{2}+\dots +\sqrt[3]{m}$

Is we solve this by induction can any help me

Comment: There is no closed-form solution.  Why would you believe that there is?  One could develop an asymptotic series for large $m$ using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.

Comment: Could the upvoters please explain why they upvoted this Problem Statement Question, with no effort or motivation given?

Answer (score 4):

There is no exact formula
for the sum in
a finite expressions.

However,
you can get bounds
from, for example,
the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

A first approximation to the sum is
$\int_0^m x^{1/3}dx
=\dfrac{x^{4/3}}{4/3}
=\frac34 m^{4/3}
$.

If $0 < a $,
then, since
$x^a$ is increasing,
$k^a < \int_k^{k+1} x^a dx
\lt (k+1)^a
$.

Using this,
you can get
upper and lower bounds
for the sum
$\sum_{k=0}^m k^a
$.

Answer (score 3):

$$S_m=\sum ^m _{k=0} \sqrt[3]{k}=H_m^{\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$ where appear the [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

If you consider large values of $m$, the asymptotics would be
$$\sum ^m _{k=0} \sqrt[3]{k}=\frac{3 }{4}m^{4/3}+\frac{1}{2}m^{1/3}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{36}
   {m^{-2/3}}+O\left({m^{-8/3}}\right)$$ where $\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\approx -0.277343$.

For $S_{10}$ an exact calculation would give $16.96411791$ while the above approximation leads to $16.96411901$ corresponding to a relative error of $6.52\times 10^{-6}$%.

For $S_{100}$, the relative error would be  $6.82\times 10^{-10}$%.